# VC++ 2010 express: How to make a image file output to the Debug directory when compiling?

Tags: visual-c++, build, resources

I'm creating a simple "hello world" vc++/opencv project.

In my code, I want to read and display an image called "opencv.png":

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    namedWindow( "show_image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    Mat src = imread( "opencv.png" );
    imshow( "show_image", src );
    char c = waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I put the "opencv.png" under the project root path. But I found when I compiling the project, the "opencv.png" won't be displayed.

In the "helloworld/Debug" directory, there are only 3 files:

```
helloworld.exe
helloworld.ilk
helloworld.pdb
```

I have to copy the "opencv.png" manually to "Debug". How to configure the project to let it copy the "opencv.png" to output dir when compiling?

---

Per James' answer, I think it's a little complicated. Is there any easier way, e.g. embed the "opencv.png" in the final exe file?

Comment: Meh, time to work on version 0.2, have it use argv[1] instead.  Now it's compatible with Windows, you can associate your exe with the .png filename extension and you can show *any* PNG file just by clicking it in Explorer.

Comment: What, exactly, do you find complicated?  The custom build step can simply be `copy "$(ProjectDir)\MyImage.png" $(OutDir)\MyImage.png`.  The custom build step can be an arbitrary command.  Passing the argument in via the command line is even less work.

Comment: You are right, it's not that complicated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Custom Build Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to perform the copy.

Alternatively, consider placing the image in some known location so that it does not need to be copied (e.g. in a TestData directory), or pass the path to the image via the command line (you can add arguments to the command line in the Debugging page of the project properties).